# Pretty Print Distances for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-location, cllocationmanager

I have two CLLocation objects and I would like the show the distance between them in a nice and pretty format. Like "22 feet", "58 yards", or "2.3 miles"

```
CLLocation *location1 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:42.333297 longitude:-71.588858];
CLLocation *location2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:42.353297 longitude:-71.578858];

float target = [location1 getDistanceFrom:location2];
```

Basically, is there anything in the iOS library that can convert a distance to a pretty string or do I have to do this manually?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, you have to do this manually.

And if you do so, please don't forget to check:

```
[[[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem] boolValue]
```

The rest of the world would appreciate.

Comment: This is no longer true. Please see Alexander's answer.

Comment: Klass Answer is more accurate. It support localization also.

Answer (score 47):

iOS 7 (and OS X 10.9) introduced [MKDistanceFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKDistanceFormatter_class/) that does exactly what you need:

```
CLLocationDistance distance = 1320.0;
MKDistanceFormatter *df = [[MKDistanceFormatter alloc]init];
df.unitStyle = MKDistanceFormatterUnitStyleFull;

NSString *prettyString = [df stringFromDistance:distance];
```

**Swift version:**

```
let distance = 1320.0
let df = MKDistanceFormatter()
df.unitStyle = .Full

let prettyString = df.stringFromDistance(distance)
```

**Swift 5.4.2:**

```
import MapKit

let distance = 1320.0
let df = MKDistanceFormatter()
df.unitStyle = .full
let prettyString = df.string(fromDistance: distance)
```

Answer (score 19):

I just wanted to note, that, as with the release of **iOS8** there will be new `NSFormatters` for exactly this kind of problem.

There will be `NSLengthFormatter`, `NSMassFormatter` and `NSEnergyFormatter` which are very easy to use – see this [**iOS8 NSFormatter tutorial**](http://www.ama-dev.com/ios8-nsformatters-nsenergyformatter-nsmassformatter-and-more/). Here is an example using the LengthFormatter with swift:

```
let lengthFormatter = LengthFormatter()
print("Kilometer: ", lengthFormatter.string(fromValue:1000, unit: .kilometer)) //Kilometer: 1,000 km
```

Like with DateFormatter, you will no longer necessarily have to use `NSLocale` for printing the unit itself.

Comment: As Klaas noted nearly a year prior to this answer, [MKDistanceFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKDistanceFormatter_class/) was added in iOS 7 and is exactly suited for this purpose.

Comment: `NSLengthFormatter` gives better options for the formatting of the numerical value, while not giving the correct output for locales where they use the metric system except for distances. `MKDistanceFormatter` unfortunately doesn't give you numerical formatting options and appears to round the numerical value.

Answer (score 4):

[TTTLocationFormatter](https://github.com/mattt/FormatterKit/tree/master/TTTLocationFormatter) from [FormatterKit](https://github.com/mattt/FormatterKit) might be exactly what you are looking for. If it isn't you can probably use it as a starting point.

Answer (score 4):

```
import Foundation

extension Double {
  var prettyDistance: String {
    guard self > -.infinity else { return "?" }

    let formatter = LengthFormatter()
    formatter.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

    if self >= 1000 {
      return formatter.string(fromValue: self / 1000, unit: LengthFormatter.Unit.kilometer)
    } else {
      let value = Double(Int(self))
      return formatter.string(fromValue: value, unit: LengthFormatter.Unit.meter)
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
Double(1).prettyDistance // 1 m
Double(10).prettyDistance // 10 m
Double(100).prettyDistance // 100 m
Double(999).prettyDistance // 999 m
Double(1000).prettyDistance // 1 km
Double(1111).prettyDistance // 1.11 km
Double(5555).prettyDistance // 5.56 km
Double(9999).prettyDistance // 10 km
Double(10000).prettyDistance // 10 km
Double(99999).prettyDistance // 100 km
Double(100000).prettyDistance // 100 km
Double(555555).prettyDistance // 555.56 km
Double(999999).prettyDistance // 1,000 km
Double(1000000).prettyDistance // 1,000 km
Double(1234567890).prettyDistance // 1,234,567.89 km
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string formatting to accomplish this:

```
//distance to 2 decimal places
NSString *target = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f miles", distance];
```

But there's no functionality for converting between distance measurements or anything like that.

Comment: I was doing the same thing, but this is not recommended. When I expanded my app to other countries, I had to change it. So you should use MKDistanceFormatter class.